# Static variable access in a cluster

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

In java,There is only one instance of static variables, and the values are shared between all threads in the same environment.But my question is When an application is deployed in a cluster ,Does the value remain same if the application is accessed and changed by different instances of the cluster ?

Or it changes and remains the same for each instance of a cluster ?

Comment: You have to specify what do you mean by a cluster? which technology you are using?

Comment: In a Glassfish App server...if i hit the deployed application from different instance machines of a single cluster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the same for each instance of JVM running in cluster. There will be different instances in differenr running JVM. And, to be more precise, as there can be multimple classloaders in within the same JVM, they will each have their own instance.

Answer (score 2):

If you are asking if multiple JVM share memory, then no, they do not.

Each JVM gets their own copy of the class and its static fields.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure of your definition of a cluster. However, if you mean different JVMs working together, then the static variable is one per JVM.
For example,
 If you have 10 JVMs in your cluster, there will be 10 instances of the static variable, each independent of one another.